# Deploying Django on Google App Engine ==> ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) NOT_FOUND: Unable to retrieve P4SA(...)

Tags: django, google-app-engine, deployment

I'm trying to deploy a Django application on Google App Engine. I followed the instructions given [here](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine#macos-64-bit). The only problem is that when I execute the command `gcloud app deploy` I than get the error:

> ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) NOT_FOUND: Unable to retrieve P4SA: [service-290226755412@gcp-gae-service.iam.gserviceaccount.com] from GAIA. Could be GAIA propagation delay or request from deleted apps.

I didn't find anything online and can't get through.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this a transient issue or a permanent one? Not sure if this is the right place to troubleshoot but could you try to deploy the [Python3 Quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/quickstart) and see if you are able to do so?

Comment: same issue when deploying a flask app

Answer (score 44):

Same problem with Node, **just waited and tryed again** the command later and that's work for me (in the same shell, no steps between).

Comment: Worked for me as well.

Answer (score 22):

I had the same problem but with flask.
I follow this tutorial of google [here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-run-hello-python3?hl=en&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fcodelabs.developers.google.com%2Feuropython%3Fhl%3Den) and When I ran the comand `gcloud app deploy` I got the same error.

My solution was to `Enable` the **Cloud Build API** service in my project (in the Navigation Menu -> CI/CD). I did that and everything worked fine and I was able to complete the tutorial.

Comment: After enabled APP Engine Admin API, worked for me.

Comment: This worked... I'm profoundly annoyed that GCP does not do this for you, or at least tell you why it's not working... I will wager to bet its why a majority of people here think the issue just suddenly "resolved" over time.. in reality they probably just mucked around in the Cloud Console aimlessly and eventually enabled the API.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue when deploying a Java application to an App Engine.

Enabling the 'Cloud Build API' under the APIs & Services section in the Google console resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error with different service ID, I deleted the specified service with that ID than it started working for me.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! Could you extend your your answer with a command or a snippet?

Answer (score 0):

> ### Got the same error, I just activated billing account on the current project on gcp and retry deploy. All works for me